# ibtool compilation error building for simulator but not for hardware

Tags: xcode

Apparently out of nowhere I've suddenly started getting a compilation error, which only occurs when building for the simulator:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

It compiled this morning, I have not changed the xib, now this afternoon it fails.

What is it and why is it only for the simulator?

EDIT - the number of errors increasing, first it was one, then I relaunched x code, then it was two, now its increased to 3.

EDIT - Now XCode crashes whenever I try to view *any* xib.

Maybe time for a reinstall

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem.  Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: I uninstalled XCode and reinstalled it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once. In my case I had edited the SourceCode of a storyboard and failed to add a file in the  section.